# Angularjs: Set a value of input of type date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This might be a stupid and an easy problem but I can't seem to have a solution to this.
I'm trying to set a field of type Date but nothing show up. Here is my code:

In Html:

```
<input type="date" name="departure" ng-model="departure" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" required/>
```

In the Controller I do something like this:

```
$scope.departure = new Date(2015, 9, 22);
```

NOTHING got display in the field "departure". I dont understand why. This seems to be so easy. 
I follow this example: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

Please help. I'm using Angular 1.3
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you set ng-controller in the html.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are just trying to get your scope variable departure to be translated into the format of the date input. I created this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vc5mWwOK2UiNdGE0cPwi).

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('stack',[]);

app.controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.departure = new Date(2015, 10, 22);
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stack">

  <head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DateController">
    <input type="date" name="departure" ng-model="departure" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" required/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Again not exactly sure what you were trying to do but this works for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just as a side note: The month index is zero-based, so `new Date(2015, 10, 22)` is the 22nd of November, 2015. Just in case anybody bumps into this.